# How to get Ansible to use python 2.7 when 2.6 is listed as python version

Tags: python

I want to install ansible.

On cent OS with python default of 2.6 I was able to upgrade the python version from 2.6 to 2.7 (as 2.7 is required for ansible)

Before installing ansible I verified the python version by running  python -V
Which resulted in Python 2.7.10

Once I installed ansible I checked the version by running `ansible --version`
which resulted in the following

```
ansible 2.6.13
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
```

How can I update the ansible python module location and python version to reference 2.7 rather than 2.6?

Answer (score 0):

I use a virtual environment for python, specifically [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/). This allows you to specify specific versions of python to be used by individual projects or applications you want to run. You are also able to install dependencies easily, and manage them all through Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks Randomhero, installing Anaconda appears to have impacted the install of ansible so  I removed Anaconda again

Comment: I haven't been able to test it, but you should be able to install ansible using anaconda and that will manage the versions of dependencies you need.
You can make an environment with 'conda create --name ansibleenv python=2.7' then activate it with 'conda activate ansibleenv'. Once you have that, you can install ansible again with 'conda install -c conda-forge ansible '.